# Why PHP setCookie() sets another variable as a cookie than I want?

Tags: php, regex, cookies

I want to set price[0] as a cookie, but it seems to set $ln as a cookie because it doesn't matter whether I write $price[0] or $ln as a parameter it shows me in both variations the same output. $price[0] is a float value.

Here is the code:

```
function getPrice($url){
  $str = file_get_contents($url);
  $lines = explode("\n",$str);
  foreach ($lines as $ln) {
    $target = 'class="text-large2" data-currency-value';
    if(strstr($ln,$target)){
      $regex = "/(.*?)<\/span/";
      preg_match($regex, $ln, $price);
      setcookie("price",$price[0],0,"/");
      break;
    }
   }
  }
```

Explanation of the code:
I get the sourcecode of a website, search for a specific line which contains $target and in this line I am searching for the price with the help of preg_match(). I want to set the first result as a cookie as already mentioned.

If necessary here the is the url I use:

```
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/";
```

I have already tried to cast price[0] to a string but it didn't help and I am running this function on a AJAX request, that's why I had to set the path in setCookie().

[Cookies which I do get setting $ln and $price[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoDhS.png)

Comment: ' it shows me in both variations the same output ' - what output do you get ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. I have added a picture at the end of my question

Comment: print  `$price[0]` before you set the value in cookie

Comment: You mean echo it?  It prints the correct and expected value.

Answer (score 0):

`setCookie` should be executed before any output (even white space) is made. So in the file containing the function , use `ob_start();` at the very first and then use all your code and then use `ob_end_flush();`

Encode the file as UTF-8 without BOM to see whether it works.

**EDIT:**    What is said above is solution to cases where `setCookie` does not work for different reasons. **The following explanation suffices for the current scenario.**

The problem the OP is facing I think is :
OP can write the following line  -

```
 setcookie("price",$price[0],0,"/");
```

as -

```
setcookie("price",$ln,0,"/");
```

and still the same result is produced.

In fact that is the expected result. With the following 2 lines:

```
$ln=htmlspecialchars($ln);
echo "<br/> ln found = ".$ln;
```

I found  the following output :

```
ln found = <span class="text-large2" data-currency-value>9740.30</span>
```

Let us look at the following 2 lines from OP:

```
 $target = 'class="text-large2" data-currency-value';
    if(strstr($ln,$target)){
```

When the `if` condition becomes `true`,then `$target` is found in `$ln`. And then `preg_match` tries to search the pattern i.e. `"/(.*?)<\/span/"`. `preg_match` stores the result in `price` as an array.  **The first element in the array (i.e. `$price[0]` variable) becomes the full `$ln` except the last `>`** i.e. `<span class="text-large2" data-currency-value>9740.30</span` . But without using `htmlspecialchars`, the HTML tags just remain **invisible**.

Now when you use `$ln` or `$price[0]` in `setCookie` ,  you get the same result i.e. 9740.30.

Comment: That is what I meant

Comment: What problem do  you face now ?

Comment: changed my answer

Comment: Same as before. Have you tried it yourself? Did it work for you?

Comment: Run it in a simple PHP script , not in an ajax call , and see the result

Comment: @AntonSarg, Added 'EDIT:' in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are only searching for a single target float in the earliest possible position in the text.  For these reasons, you don't need to `explode()`, you don't need to loop, and you certainly should not be using `strstr()` to search for the existence of a substring string. ([Read Note #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php))

```
function getPrice($url){
    $str=file_get_contents($url);
    if(preg_match('~<span class="text-large2"\s+data-currency-value>\K\d+.\d+~',$str,$out)){
        setcookie('price',$out[0],0,'/');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`\K` will restart the fullstring match, this means `[0]` will contain the desired value.  In your coding attempt, you used a capture group -- which was Capture Group #1 -- and were trying to access the fullstring match instead (`[0]`).  This is why you keep getting the full `$ln`.

Furthermore, with very few exceptions, functions should `return` something.  If matching was successful return true, else return false.  This give you the ability to write some kind of conditional alert in your application.

I was not able to test my pattern, since your question does not provide sample input.  If my answer doesn't work for you, please improve your question.